# Php form to work with this otp based code login

Tags: php, forms, api, rest

This code is used to send request to the server to obtain token

This code will send the otp

````
   const URL = 'https://api.gotinder.com/';```


``` /**
    * Sends SMS message to user to verify their account
    *
    * @param string $phoneNumber Your phone number associated with your tinder account
    *
    * @throws
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function requestCode($phoneNumber)
   {
       $number_plus = $phoneNumber;
       $number = ltrim($number_plus, '+');
       $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $number);
       $code = $this->getCode($number);
        try {
           $response = $this->client->post(self::URL . '/v3/auth/login?locale=en', [
               'body' =>  $code.$number,
               'headers' => $headers
           ]);
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           return $e->getMessage();
       }

       return $response->getBody()->getContents();
   }
````

This code will validate the otp

```
    /**
     * Sends SMS message to user to verify their account
     *
     * @param string $phoneNumber Your phone number associated with your tinder account
     *
     * @throws
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function validateCode($phoneNumber, $code)
    {
       $data = ['otp_code' => $code, 'phone_number' => $phoneNumber, 'is_update' => false];

        try {
            $response = $this->client->post(self::URL . '/v2/auth/sms/validate?auth_type=sms&locale=en', [
                'json' => $data,
                'headers' => $headers
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }
```

This code will get the token based on refresh

```
    /**
     * Gets Token based upon users Refresh Token
     *
     * @param string $token Tinder access token
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTokenFromRefreshToken($token)
    {
        $responseArray = $this->makePostRequest($token, '/v2/auth/login/sms');

        return $responseArray['data'];
    }
```

I am trying create video based on this. Thanks for the help in advance .

I am stuck in the part where the frontend will make request to retrieve this token

Comment: Just on a side note, you don't need the `ltrim()` if you're stripping all non-digit chars on the next line with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail. Where are you getting stuck? Share any errors you're getting. What have you tried so far? Also please elaborate on your final goal, as it is very vague what you mean by 'trying to create  video'.

Comment: I am trying to create a form where i can enter my phone. So it will ask me for the otp them I have to enter otp which will give me back the access token

Comment: You're still not describing _what is going wrong_. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://ibb.co/2nxBrYV

Comment: https://ibb.co/X7NcZPh